# How to make a globally available style WITHOUT App.xaml

Tags: wpf, window, styles, themes, class-library

I have a class library I am creating for an AutoCAD plugin that includes WPF control elements. I would like to add a theme to these elements, so I added the WPFThemes.DarkBlend package from Nuget.

To property utilize the theme, you are supposed to add the style reference to your App.xaml file like so:

```
<Application
...
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes\Styles.xaml” />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now unfortunately, because this is only a class library, I do not have an App.xaml file in which to add this code. I am able to use my Window.Resources, but in doing so, I am afraid that the styles in the reference are not exposed to the Window element. Is this because the Window is not within the scope of its own resources? Below is an image that shows my current situation:

[image: The style is not available to the Window control element]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating an x:Key  in the style called "DarkWindow", I found that I was able to apply the style directly in the PluginWindow.xaml window properties like this:

```
<Window Style="{DynamicResource DarkWindow}" />
```

Comment: Does it applied globally to all the windows?